# Entity Framework Table Per Hierarchy(TPH) Guid foreign key discriminator error

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have a Table per Hierarchy but when i made a Guid foreign key as the discriminator column, the migration failed with error:-**Condition can not be specified on values of member ''. Value conditions are not supported for type 'SqlServer.uniqueidentifier'**.

This is my configuration of one of my derived classes

Map(m => m.Requires("TypeId").HasValue("58287E26-7D9C-4CA3-84FA-163D7DD911B6"));

note:- i also tried with Map(m => m.Requires("TypeId").HasValue(new Guid("58287E26-7D9C-4CA3-84FA-163D7DD911B6"))); but also, the same error happened
[image]

Comment: Hi yo2011, I've come across the same issue now, did you have any luck finding a solution to this?

Comment: No, i didn't find any solution and i added an issue at Entity Framework codeplex

Comment: hi Anupheaus; have you solved this issue?

Comment: No, I changed my design to be TPT rather than TPH; I am convincing myself that is the best workaround by saying that any additional fields I need per type I can just add to the table now. In reality (at the moment); I've now got a database full of one column tables :(

Comment: I know that EF7 prerelease is now available (and is beta 4) so maybe it's been fixed/modified so that you can use a GUID now (especially since it is now all code first afaik) so it might be worth looking into that?

Comment: did you try it on EF7?

Comment: Nope, not yet.  I might give it a go one evening this week but I haven't had chance yet.

Comment: thanks; if you solved it, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Your discriminator can't be a foreign key: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/24380ee6-4753-46a2-a3ed-b1cb2e2d161c/edm-tph-with-foreign-key-as-discriminator-column?forum=adodotnetentityframework

Comment: It doesn't work and give me this error:-Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
(19,12) : error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type 'Edm.Guid[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=]' of member 'TypeId' in type '' is not compatible with 'SqlServer.nvarchar[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,MaxLength=4000,Unicode=True,FixedLength=False]' of member 'TypeId' in type ''.

Comment: Note, The discriminator column must be foreign key and must be of type Guid

Comment: Have you tried casting the GUID back to a sting? new Guid("58287E26-7D9C-4CA3-84FA-163D7DD911B6").ToString()

Comment: Yes, but nothing happened

Comment: any help for this critical issue or another solution to implement this schema in Entity Framework